# Hierarchical Select entity reference between three content types?

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms

I have three content types: *Courses*, *Sections*, and *Chapters*. *Sections* has an entity reference field for *Courses*; *Chapters* has two entity reference fields, one for *Courses* and one for *Sections*.

If I select the *Courses* corresponding section, I have to list out the *Chapters*. I need a hierarchical structure.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You could try the [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module. [Update multiple fields with AJAX callback in form](https://www.drupal.org/node/1408994) may also help you.

Comment: Please can u explain how to use conditional_fields module

Comment: it's doesn't work for me. Any idea u have it?

Comment: you could use a view to build the list of nodes that will be the field values taking previous field :nid as an argument